# How to get @wire service promise instance

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am working with spinner and this spinner should executive on based on the start and stop of @wire service async callout. Could I get help to find the @wire async callout promise instance? so based on this instance I will executive my spinner logic.

For example: for Apex Method Imperatively function

```
    createAccount() {
    const fields = this.fields;
    const recordInput = { apiName: 'Account', fields };
    let callout  = createRecord(recordInput)
      .then(account => {
        this.accountId = account.id;
      });
    this.loadSpinner(callout);
  }

 loadSpinner(callout){
    this.spinner = true;
    callout.finally(() => { this.spinner = false });
}
```

This is how I am executing the spinner from Apex Method Imperatively function but unfortunately, I am not able to find the same for the @wire service.

Answer (score 1):

Create a property that controls the render state of your spinner and set it's default value to true.

**JS**

```
@track isLoading = true;
@wire(/*METHOD*/)
wireThings(response) {
    const wiredMethod = response;
    const {data,error} = response;
    if(data) {
        this.isLoading = false;
    }
    if(error) {
        this.isLoading = false;
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<lightning-spinner if:true={isLoading}></lightning-spinner>
```

This property can be toggled for any subsequent callouts.

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry, this would not help me. let's say If I have 4 dynamic parameters and it has 4 different on change function and each function i would need to add the isLoading = true;. In the future, if I create a new parameter then I would need to change spinner logic again. I am looking very generic function that would handle automatically the spinner load. Thank you replyed me